# Using dup and clone both end up modifying the record in which is was built from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I've built-out a mechanism to go and find an auto-generated invoice and update it with new information when a plan is changed or if users are added to the plan for the current billing period. It will make it a lot easier than having to remember to change it a month, quarter, 6 months, or even a year from now. And this also reduces the burden on the finance department from having to go find the future invoice and manually updating it. I hope my comments in the code are clear.

I'm running into a roadblock with `first_manual_invoice`. I would prefer to just cal `dup` or `clone` on `manual_invoice`; however, when the code runs a second or third time, the future invoice continues to be divided by the term frequency. Any ideas to dup this record? I don't want to rely on it's parent from which is was built from (which is what I am doing now).

```
  # Finds the upcoming / unpaid system invoice.
  manual_invoice = @subscription.manual_invoices.system.not_paid.latest.first

  # TODO: This is very hacky. If I use dup or clone on manual_invoice, and
  #   when change_plan is executed, the calculation runs, regardless if
  #   there were any updates. Also, chaining these scopes brings back all
  #   of the records when using .latest... so, I end up with an invoice
  #   where paid_at is nil.
  first_manual_invoice = @subscription.manual_invoices.system.paid.first

  # Guards changing of plan from blowing up if manual_invoice.nil?
  if manual_invoice
    subscription_term_type = @subscription.term_type
    # Iterate through the invoice's items.
    first_manual_invoice.items.each do |item|
      # Set new_amount by taking the new max_users quantity and multiply it
      #   by the previous amount. Then divide it by the previous max_users
      #   quantity. Finally, divide by payment frequency per term.
      new_amount = ((max_users.to_i * item.amount) / item.quantity)
      if subscription_term_type == 'month'
        new_amount = new_amount / 12
      elsif subscription_term_type == 'quarter'
        new_amount = new_amount / 4
      elsif subscription_term_type == 'semiannual'
        new_amount = new_amount / 2
      elsif subscription_term_type == 'annual'
        new_amount = new_amount / 1
      end

      # Update the manual_invoice items with the calcuated new_amount and
      #   user quantity.
      manual_invoice.items.first.update_attributes(quantity: max_users,
                                                   amount: new_amount)
      # Update the manual_invoice.
      manual_invoice.update_attributes(amount_in_cents: new_amount,
                                       term_type: term_type,
                                       term_start_date: term_start_date,
                                       term_end_date: term_end_date,
                                       due_on: term_end_date)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you want. 
But about duplicate record, I recommend [amoeba](https://github.com/amoeba-rb/amoeba) gem. This is helpful gem for cloning of active_record objects including associations and several operations under associations and attributes.